# Simple HTML5 game not work in android WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I wrote a simple game on js - it works even on InternetExplorer, it doesn’t work in WebView - only HTML code is displayed, js is not executed.However, if leave only such code in js:

```
ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(back,0,0,400,500);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.font = "30px Georgia";
ctx.fillText("Super Game", 10, 30);
```

then js code is executed.

My full code:

HTML5 Game:

https://jsfiddle.net/ce1xvuwh/

Android code:

```
package com.example.android_rodnoj_kod;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        WebView myWebView = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(myWebView);

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/simple_game.html");


    }
}
```

and AndroidManifest.xml:

> package="com.example.android_rodnoj_kod">
>
> ```
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>     <activity android:name="com.example.android_rodnoj_kod.MainActivity">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> </application>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> </manifest>
> ```

Comment: Try to debug webview, add `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)` and open `chrome://inspect`. Now you can view inside it :)

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode.what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved - the whole point was that I used **"let"** instead of **"var"** in one function - this caused an exception.
thanks - https://stackoverflow.com/users/5279156/vlad